# not able to open a file from share drive

Tags: c#

I was trying to browse a file(S:\Scalable Development\DRD_ToolPointManagement.doc) from shared location trough web browser using application. when I run my application in local, it is working where as if I push the code to dev and QA environment, not able to open a file

Comment: You'll need to post more detail than that.  See [ask].

Comment: What platform are you and the QA environment running? Note that accessing mapped drives from code won't work on Windows8, you have to use the UNC path

Answer (score 0):

There are two different problems, firstly using a mapped drive and secondly access rights to the folder. Both of these depend upon which account the application is running under. Have a look at http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

You need the built in group IIS_WPG which covers the application pool to have access to the network drive. If the S: drive is not mapped on the web server, you will also need to use the UNC path. If you look in Windows Explorer, your S: drive will appear something like

`myshare (\\myserver) (S:)` which should be translated to `\\myserver\myshare\Scalable Development\DRD_ToolPointManagement.doc`

Your domain administrator may need to allow access to the network share, and you may need to consider [impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Looks like my web server doesn't have permissions to access the file                   System.IO.File.Exists(S:\Scalable Development\DRD_ToolPointManagement.doc) is returning false when I run it on my web server. How would I verify if my web server has access to the S Drive?

Answer (score -1):

When using the Web browser control, you're using the Internet Explorer. Thus, security settings may apply.

You need to change these in the Control Panel's internet settings of every machine you want to deploy to.

For example you may have to add the location to the trusted zone. Also, the target IE may not be configured to open Office documents in-place.